# HTML Canvas clearRect & Redraw Performance

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a web based drawing board. Part of the functionality of this is to draw shapes (like lines).

I'm finding myself needing to keep track of all the points drawn in the canvas in an array. Specifically because I need to clear the board and redraw the points when drawing lines and other shapes to make it feel "interactive". To clarify the functionality, I've created this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hwa95rcx/35/

HTML:

```
<canvas id="test" width="500" height="500">
</canvas>
```

JavasScript:

```
let lineStartX = 0;
let lineStartY = 0;
const drawingPoints = [];
let mouseDown = false;
const c = document.getElementById("test");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.onmousedown = (e) => {
  lineStartX = e.clientX;
  lineStartY = e.clientY;
  mouseDown = true;
}
c.onmousemove = (e) => {
  if (mouseDown) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    redraw();
    ctx.moveTo(lineStartX, lineStartY);
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();


  }
}
c.onmouseup = (e) => {
  mouseDown = false;
  drawingPoints.push({
    startX: lineStartX,
    startY: lineStartY,
    lineEndX: e.clientX,
    lineEndY: e.clientY
  });
}

function redraw() {
  drawingPoints.forEach(el => {
    ctx.moveTo(el.startX, el.startY);
    ctx.lineTo(el.lineEndX, el.lineEndY);
    ctx.stroke()
  });
}
```

that exemplifies the reason I need to store an array of points to redraw.

I would like to avoid doing this because at large quantities of data, the drawing slows down or even crashes because we are looping through all the points to redraw them. Is there a more performant way of achieving this interactive shape drawing effect I am looking for?

Comment: For all kind of drawings using vector-like functions, you can use svg and change dynamically all attributes of svg sub elements... It's probably a better way to get good performance, and you can export it to a canvas at the end of user interaction by using drawImage method with svg input.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use an SVG separate from the canvas and have its properties dynamically change? I don't quite understand how can utilize an svg with a canvas without placing the svg in it. Once drawn to the canvas, I don't believe I can modify the attributes of the svg. Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding you

Comment: Don't use an svg for this. Rendering an svg is more complex than rendering a canvas. For such an application, every performance issues you'll have with a canvas will just be worst with an svg. Storing all the vectors in DOM objects will always be worst than storing simple js objects.

Comment: The rendering turns to be very slow with canvas when dealing with large number of objects... SVG does NOT have this issue since every object drawn stays in place and does not need to be redrawed at each action.
And to @TheScreenSlaver : yes you can animate values inside svg attributes

Comment: @FabienAuréjac This is completely wrong. When an svg inner element is modified the whole svg image is rerendered. In a browser svg elements are just very complicated canvases. You can draw magnitudes more elements on a canvas than on an svg. OP was doing "something wrong", that's all there is here. Using an svg for this is a very bad advice.

Comment: If this were wrong this kind of pages would render as fast with canvas as with svg : https://studioavantgarde.fr
Just give it a try an tell me you would be able to make it with a canvas based animation. I've plenty of examples for this kind of issue.

Comment: also as long as you would not need raster, svg is a better choice to keep your drawing in the vector space... This is the solution used by boxysvg.

Comment: @FabienAuréjac Yep, pretty sure I can get even better perfs with a canvas that what you got there with SVG. But that's not the point anyway. Nothing in that page compares to what OP is doing. Please keep focused on the question at hand. I'm not saying that SVG has no use, it obviously has, but for what OP is doing and given the question at hand using SVG is a very bad idea. Here is an actual comparison: [canvas](https://jsfiddle.net/4jy032d6/) (not even the fastest version) vs [svg](https://jsfiddle.net/4jy032d6/1/). Canvas clearly outperforms SVG on my machine.

Comment: your demo is also unfair regarding the dpi. svg will adapt it self on the dpi of the machine, here on a 4k screen the svg canvas does not reduce to 500x500px, and your canvas appears blurry with 500x500px.

Answer (score 0):

Your `redraw` function calls `stroke()` for every sub-segment, but never calls `beginPath()`. This means that when you have two sub-segments, the first one will get painted at its own turn, and then again when the second sub-segment calls `stroke()`.
You can see this quite clearly by looking at your first strokes and how their antialiasing darkens the more sub-segments there are.
You are actually asking the computer to render magnitudes more items than required, this is what is making your app slow and eventually crash.

So you could call `beginPath()` in the loop, but the best is instead to remove entirely `stroke()` from there. This way, at every frame you only paint one single path. The GPU has only one single operation to do and you should be fine for days of drawings.

```js
let lineStartX = 0;
let lineStartY = 0;
const drawingPoints = [];
let mouseDown = false;
const c = document.getElementById("test");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.onmousedown = (e) => {
  lineStartX = e.clientX;
  lineStartY = e.clientY;
  mouseDown = true;
}
c.onmousemove = (e) => {
  if (mouseDown) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    redraw();
    ctx.moveTo(lineStartX, lineStartY);
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
c.onmouseup = (e) => {
  mouseDown = false;
  drawingPoints.push({
    startX: lineStartX,
    startY: lineStartY,
    lineEndX: e.clientX,
    lineEndY: e.clientY
  });
}

function redraw() {
  // 'redraw' only traces the previous sub-segments
  drawingPoints.forEach(el => {
    ctx.moveTo(el.startX, el.startY);
    ctx.lineTo(el.lineEndX, el.lineEndY);
  });
}
```

```html
<canvas id="test" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Note that if you measure that even the tracing takes some computation time (though this would be surprising), you may want to try storing the sub-path in a Path2D object instead of calling the drawing methods every time:

```js
let lineStartX = 0;
let lineStartY = 0;
const path = new Path2D();
let mouseDown = false;
const c = document.getElementById("test");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.onmousedown = (e) => {
  lineStartX = e.clientX;
  lineStartY = e.clientY;
  mouseDown = true;
}
c.onmousemove = (e) => {
  if (mouseDown) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    redraw();
    ctx.moveTo(lineStartX, lineStartY);
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
c.onmouseup = (e) => {
  mouseDown = false;
  path.moveTo(lineStartX, lineStartY);
  path.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}

function redraw() {
  ctx.stroke(path);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="test" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```